# pyqt5. Добавление события для отрисовывания прямой линии

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

```
...

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = True
            self.LastPoint = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton) & self.drawing:
            painter = QPainter(self.image)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
            painter.drawLine(self.LastPoint, event.pos())
            self.LastPoint = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = False
                                         
   

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        canvasPainter = QPainter(self)
        canvasPainter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image, self.image.rect())

    def save(self):
        file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save Image", "",
                                                   "File PNG(*.png);;File JPEG(*.jpg *.jpeg);;All Files(*.*) ")

        if file_path == "":
            return
        self.image.save(file_path)


    def clear(self):
        self.image.fill(self.background)
        self.update()

    def draw_line(self): #ВОТ СЮДА ДОБАВИТЬ ОТРИСОВКУ
                          
            

    def image_black(self):
        self.background = Qt.black
        self.image.fill(self.background)
        self.update()

...
```

[Полный код](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VZqe8YlaPRJnEyOaWlqO4-1QuN1-EPf0/view?usp=sharing)

[Файл для QtDesigner](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YBfF2IQmAC15f5tFYUr5uu3Rgtm46qOI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Пример линии, или пример моего кода, но короткий?

Comment: Именно мой код отправить не получится. Я хочу событие отрисовки прямой линии привязать к Qt Designer'у. Чтобы можно было просто рисовать мышью, а линию по выбору из инструментов взять. Как в paint'e. Поэтому два файла у меня.

Comment: И я вот не знаю, как лучше всё это оформить, чтобы понятно было

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй вариант. Настройки цвета, ширины и т.д. сделаете самостоятельно.

**main.py**

```
import sys, random
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint, QLineF


class Paint(QMainWindow):
#?    def func_lhndsgcq(self):
#?        return 

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Paint, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi('risovalka.ui', self)

        title = "risovalka"

        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setFixedSize(700, 700)

        self.background = Qt.white

        self.image = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_RGB32)
        self.image.fill(self.background)

        self.drawing = False
        self.color = Qt.black
        self.brushSize = 1
        self.brushColor = Qt.black
        self.LastPoint = QPoint()
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.lines = []
        self.drawing = False
        self.startPoint = None
        self.endPoint = None
        self.pixelSpacing = 2
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.actionSave.triggered.connect(self.save)
        self.actionClose.triggered.connect(self.clear)
        self.actionBlack.triggered.connect(self.image_black)
        self.actionGray.triggered.connect(self.image_gray)
        self.actionRed.triggered.connect(self.image_red)
        self.actionYellow.triggered.connect(self.image_yellow)
        self.actionBlue.triggered.connect(self.image_blue)
        self.actionGreen.triggered.connect(self.image_green)
        self.actionWhite.triggered.connect(self.image_white)
        self.actionOpen_Pallete.triggered.connect(self.open_pallete)
        self.action3px.triggered.connect(self.three_px)
        self.action3px_2.triggered.connect(self.eraser_3)
        self.action5px.triggered.connect(self.five_px)
        self.action5px_2.triggered.connect(self.eraser_5)
        self.action7px.triggered.connect(self.seven_px)
        self.action7px_2.triggered.connect(self.eraser_7)
        self.action9px.triggered.connect(self.nine_px)
        self.action9px_2.triggered.connect(self.eraser_9)
        self.action11px.triggered.connect(self.eraser_11)
        self.action15px.triggered.connect(self.eraser_15)
        # self.actionline.triggered.connect(self.drawline) #Соединение Qt Designer c кодом

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
#            self.drawing = True
#            self.LastPoint = event.pos()
#
            self.startPoint = event.pos()                                       # +++

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
#        if (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton) & self.drawing:
#            painter = QPainter(self.image)
#            painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
#            painter.drawLine(self.LastPoint, event.pos())
#            self.LastPoint = event.pos()
#            self.update()
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        if self.startPoint:                                                     # +++
            self.endPoint = event.pos()                                         # +++
            self.update()                                                       # +++
            

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
#        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
#            self.drawing = False
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        if self.startPoint and self.endPoint:
            line = QLineF(self.startPoint, self.endPoint)                  # !!! QLineF
            self.lines.append({
                'points': line, 
                'distance': round(line.length(), 2) * self.pixelSpacing, 
            })
            self.startPoint = self.endPoint = None
            self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
#        canvasPainter = QPainter(self)
#        canvasPainter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image, self.image.rect())
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHints(painter.Antialiasing)
        dirtyRect = event.rect()
        painter.drawImage(dirtyRect, QImage(self.image), dirtyRect)
        
        if self.startPoint and self.endPoint:
            painter.drawLine(self.startPoint, self.endPoint)
            
        linePen = QPen(Qt.red, 3, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin)
        
        for lineData in self.lines:
            line = lineData['points']            
            painter.setPen(linePen)
            painter.drawLine(line.p1(), line.p2())
            painter.setPen(Qt.blue)
            painter.drawText(line.p2() + QPoint(0, 10), 
                '{} mm'.format(lineData['distance']))
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 


    def save(self):
        file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
            self, "Save Image", "",
            "File PNG(*.png);;File JPEG(*.jpg *.jpeg);;All Files(*.*) ")

        if file_path == "":
            return
        self.image.save(file_path)

    #def drawline(self): СЮДА ОТРИСОВКУ

    def clear(self):
        self.image.fill(self.background)
        self.update()            

    def image_black(self):
        self.background = Qt.black
        self.image.fill(self.background)
        self.update()

    def image_red(self):
        self.background = Qt.red
        self.image.fill(self.background)
        self.update()

    def image_yellow(self):
        self.background = Qt.yellow
        self.image.fill(self.background)
        self.update()

    def image_blue(self):
        self.background = Qt.blue
        self.image.fill(self.background)
        self.update()

    def image_green(self):
        self.background = Qt.green
        self.image.fill(self.background)
        self.update()

    def image_gray(self):
        self.background = Qt.gray
        self.image.fill(self.background)
        self.update()

    def image_white(self):
        self.background = Qt.white
        self.image.fill(self.background)
        self.update()

    def three_px(self):
        self.brushColor = self.color
        self.brushSize = 3

    def five_px(self):
        self.brushColor = self.color
        self.brushSize = 5

    def seven_px(self):
        self.brushColor = self.color
        self.brushSize = 7

    def nine_px(self):
        self.brushColor = self.color
        self.brushSize = 9

    def eraser_3(self):
        self.brushSize = 3
        self.brushColor = self.background

    def eraser_5(self):
        self.brushSize = 5
        self.brushColor = self.background

    def eraser_7(self):
        self.brushSize = 7
        self.brushColor = self.background

    def eraser_9(self):
        self.brushSize = 9
        self.brushColor = self.background

    def eraser_11(self):
        self.brushSize = 11
        self.brushColor = self.background

    def eraser_15(self):
        self.brushSize = 15
        self.brushColor = self.background

    def open_pallete(self):
        self.color = QColorDialog.getColor()
        if self.color.isValid():
            self.brushColor = self.color


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Paint()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**risovalka.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>553</width>
    <height>443</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="mouseTracking">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="tabletTracking">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="autoFillBackground">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget"/>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>553</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Файл</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionClose"/>
    <addaction name="actionSave"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuBrush_Size">
    <property name="tearOffEnabled">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string>Кисть</string>
    </property>
    <property name="separatorsCollapsible">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="toolTipsVisible">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <addaction name="action3px"/>
    <addaction name="action5px"/>
    <addaction name="action7px"/>
    <addaction name="action9px"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuBrush_Color">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Выбрать цвет</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionOpen_Pallete"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuPaper_Color">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Цвет заливки фона</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionBlack"/>
    <addaction name="actionGray"/>
    <addaction name="actionRed"/>
    <addaction name="actionYellow"/>
    <addaction name="actionBlue"/>
    <addaction name="actionGreen"/>
    <addaction name="actionWhite"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuInstruments">
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string>Ластик</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="action3px_2"/>
    <addaction name="action5px_2"/>
    <addaction name="action7px_2"/>
    <addaction name="action9px_2"/>
    <addaction name="action11px"/>
    <addaction name="action15px"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuline">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Линия</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionline"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
   <addaction name="menuBrush_Size"/>
   <addaction name="menuInstruments"/>
   <addaction name="menuBrush_Color"/>
   <addaction name="menuPaper_Color"/>
   <addaction name="menuline"/>
  </widget>
  <action name="actionClose">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Очистить</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionSave">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Сохранить</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionUndo_Typing">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Undo Typing</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionRedo">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Redo</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action3px">
   <property name="text">
    <string>3px</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action5px">
   <property name="text">
    <string>5px</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action7px">
   <property name="text">
    <string>7px</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action9px">
   <property name="text">
    <string>9px</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionBlack">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Черный</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionRed">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Красный</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionYellow">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Желтый</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionBlue">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Голубой</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionGreen">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Зеленый</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionGray">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Серый</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionOpen_Pallete">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Палитра</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action3px_2">
   <property name="text">
    <string>3px</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action5px_2">
   <property name="text">
    <string>5px</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action7px_2">
   <property name="text">
    <string>7px</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action9px_2">
   <property name="text">
    <string>9px</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action11px">
   <property name="text">
    <string>11px</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action15px">
   <property name="text">
    <string>15px</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionPlay_Go">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Play_Go</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionRectengle">
   <property name="text">
    <string>
Rectangle</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionCircle">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Circle</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionSquare">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Square</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionVertical_line">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Vertical Line</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionHorizontal_Line">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Horizontal Line</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionopen">
   <property name="text">
    <string>open</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionWhite">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Белый</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionline">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Прямая</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое <3

Comment: Правда все остальное работать перестало и кисть и ластик :)

Comment: @chaser128 я же вам написал, что сами подстроите. Если что-то не будет получаться - зададите новый вопрос.

Comment: всё хорошо, я сделал.Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Вы не предоставили свой минимально-воспроизводимый пример, поэтому я вам покажу один из возможных вариантов рисовании линий.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Instruction:
    def paint(self, painter):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class LineInstruction(Instruction):
    def __init__(self, line):
        self._line = line
    def paint(self, painter):
        painter.drawLine(self._line)


class ContextTest:
    instructions = []


class MyForm(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.drawing = []

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(QtGui.QPen(
            QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255), 
            5, 
            QtCore.Qt.SolidLine, 
            QtCore.Qt.RoundCap, 
            QtCore.Qt.RoundJoin
        ))
        for instruction in ContextTest.instructions:
            instruction.paint(qp)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.start = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        l = QtCore.QLine(self.start, event.pos())
        instruction = LineInstruction(l)
        ContextTest.instructions.append(instruction)
        self.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyForm()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я добавил ссылку на сам проект. Если вам не лень, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @chaser128  Вы будете смеяться, но у меня нет rara.

Comment: Не буду смеяться) Сейчас тогда без rara сделаю

Comment: Исправил, посмотрите, пожалуйста.